# Can't import compiled cython function after successful compilation

Tags: python, cython

I'm testing out Cython on Windows 10 (Spyder 3.2.3) and Python 3.6.3 following the [Tutorial](http://docs.cython.org/en/latest/src/tutorial/cython_tutorial.html), and I wrote this function:

```
from libc.stdlib cimport malloc, free

cdef int** t3(int* El, int lEl):
    cdef int lElsq = lEl*lEl
    cdef int i,j
    cdef int** rr = <int**> malloc(2*sizeof(int*))
    for i in range(2):
        rr[i] = <int*> malloc(lElsq*sizeof(int))
    for i in range(lEl):
        for j in range(lEl):
            rr[0][i*lEl+j] = El[i]
            rr[1][i*lEl+j] = El[j]
    return rr
```

I put it into a `pyx` file and following the tutorial compiled it using the MS Visual Studio 14 compiler.

Command: `%run setup.py build_ext --inplace`

Setup file:

```
from distutils.core import setup
from Cython.Build import cythonize

setup(
    ext_modules=cythonize("tempCython.pyx"),
)
```

The compilation didn't throw any error and a lot of files were created:

In the same directory as the original file:

- a `tempCython.c` file of the same name
- a `tempCython.cp36-win_amd64.pyd` file

In the subdirectory `build\temp.win-amd64-3.6\Release`:

- a `tempCython.obj` file
- a `tempCython.cp36-win_amd64.exp` file
- a `tempCython.cp36-win_amd64.lib` file

The [Cython tutorial](http://docs.cython.org/en/latest/src/tutorial/cython_tutorial.html) tells me I need the `pyd` file, so I removed the `cp36-win_amd64` in the filename.

I can import it without error, but my function `t3` just never shows up, it's simply not there.

Without any kind of error message I'm at a loss now. I have encountered errors like these before sometimes in 3rd-party packages, but I never understood what caused them. Why is my function not there?

I'd also like to know the point of all those additional files, which ones do I actually need?

Comment: http://docs.cython.org/en/latest/src/userguide/language_basics.html#python-functions-vs-c-functions

Comment: Thanks. You can make that an answer and I'll give you points.

Comment: But that's be a link only answer...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You have written a `cdef` function and are trying to call it from python. Unfortunately, `cdef` functions are not visible from python (see http://docs.cython.org/en/latest/src/userguide/language_basics.html#python-functions-vs-c-functions) so you need to do a little bit more work to expose your function to python. In particular you would need to write either a `def` function or a `cpdef` function that calls your `cdef` function and then call *that* function from python.

Comment: I'm doing as you say but still getting a "no attribute" error.  I'm using a  `def` function that basically says `return cfunction(params)`.

Comment: Hard to help unless you share a full runnable example and full error message. Probably best to just ask a question yourself.